# how to display an image in a image control whose path is stored in db using mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How can i display an image in image control whose path is stored in database.
Please provide me with sample code i have get the path from database but how can i show in in image control .
here is my code

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DisplayPic()
    {
        string UserName=User.Identity.Name;
        var getPath = from p in Session.Query<Registration>()
                      where p.Email == UserName
                      select p.Path;
        if (getPath.Count() > 0)
        {
           //display pic???

        }

        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
     @{
        ViewBag.Title = "DisplayPic";
      }

    <h2>DisplayPic</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())

   {
     <img alt="" src="" width="200" height="200" />
   }
```

Comment: Add a string variable to your model (say 'ImageUrl') and

Comment: This is giving me an error Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference.How can i pass the value of ImageUrl in img src that i have get from db in DisplayPic Method.

Answer (score 2):

Store image path in your model property and use

```
<img src="@Url.Content(Model.ImagePath)" alt = "Image" />
```

Comment: I ditnot get how it will display the profile image of a particular user.I have get the path of the image that i want to show but i how can i give that path to image src.

Comment: provide an additional property in your model class for the imagepath