# Unable to read View Bag value from controller to view

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-4, ravendb

I have created a view bag in controller's post back event which stores the image path.
Then,i used this view bag value in image src attribute.But image is not displayed.

Model:

```
public class FileManagement
     {
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
      }
```

Code for uploading image

```
      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult UploadPic(FileManagement fmanage, HttpPostedFileBase file)
      {
        string email = User.Identity.Name;

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var FileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", Guid.NewGuid(), Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads"), FileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);

         using (var session = DocumentStore.OpenSession("RavenMemberShip"))
            {

                var query = from q in Session.Query<Registration>() where q.Email == email select q;
                if (query.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var updated in query)
                    {
                        updated.FileName = FileName;
                        updated.Path = path;
                        session.SaveChanges();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else ModelState.AddModelError("", "Remove the errors and try again");
        return View();
    }
```

Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DisplayPic()
    {
        ViewBag.Imagepath = "C:\\Users\\Wasfa\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\MvcMembership\\MvcMembership\\App_Data\\Uploads\\annonymous.jpg";

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DisplayPic(FileManagement fm)
    {


        using (var session = DocumentStore.OpenSession("RavenMemberShip"))
        {
            string ipath;
            //  string UserName = User.Identity.Name;
            string UserName = "wasfa_anjum@yahoo.com";
            var getPath = from p in Session.Query<Registration>()
                          where p.Email == UserName
                          select p;
            if (getPath.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var imgpath in getPath)
                {

                    ipath = imgpath.Path;
                    ViewBag.Imagepath = ipath;
                }

           }

        }
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())

   {
    <div>
    <img src="@Url.Content(ViewBag.Imagepath)" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Display" />
   }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19049374/2121389

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, your problem is not to do with ASP.NET MVC, but you are missing some HTML/Web basics.

You have to understand that when you want to access a resource (html file, image etc), you have to  use the HTTP URI syntax. You cannot and should not use your Windows file system path syntax.

Using something like `C:\\Users\\Wasfa\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\MvcMembership\\MvcMembership\\App_Data\\Uploads\\annonymous.jpg"` in HTML is completely wrong. To understand it better, imagine when you have your ASP.NET MVC website up and running for its users to access, they will come to you web page and the HTML downloaded on their browser will be:

```
<img src="C:\Users\Wasfa\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MvcMembership\MvcMembership\App_Data\Uploads\annonymous.jpg" />
```

Do you think that path will exist on their computers? No.

So, to instruct the `<img />` tag to fetch the image from the server, you have to specify either a full HTTP URI, for example:

```
<img src="http://mywebsite.com/Content/Uploads/annonymous.jpg" />
```

or a relative HTTP URI (which is like a relative path from your web site's root folder):

```
<img src="~/Content/Uploads/annonymous.jpg" />
```

Another problem with your approach is that `App_Data` is a special folder and its contents are not accessible from the browser by default. So, as per ASP.NET MVC convention, you can create a `Content` folder in your project to hold your static images and other static content like style sheels, and then link to them.

Once you do that, no one stops you from providing the relative path for your default image as a ViewBag property.

```
ViewBag.Imagepath = "~/Content/Uploads/annonymous.jpg";
```

And then use it the way you want:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(ViewBag.Imagepath)" width="200" height="200" />
```

I also expect the paths you subsequently fetch from the database, also follow this scheme.

Comment: +1, Good explanation, But still using ViewBag is a bad idea, that is what models are for !

Comment: @Athiban: Yes, agree with you. I just did not want to complicate the answer for someone who looks fairly new  to web programming. Hopefully  they will learn it eventually.

Answer (score 1):

- path for image must have forward slash (/),
- more over this type of path might work only in your local system and not in your server.
- Try using `Server.MapPath` to fetch your path
- Using ViewBag for displaying image is a bad idea, consider using your model property to store the image path and use

  `<img src="@Url.Content(Model.ImagePath)" alt = "Image" />`

**EDIT** :

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DisplayPic()
    {
        FileManagement fm = new FileManagement();
        fm.Path = "Your image path";

        return View(fm);
    }
```

View :

```
`<img src="@Url.Content(Model.path)" alt = "Image" />`
```

didn't check the code, but this should work.

Comment: In db path is stored as // slash.I really not get how Model.Path will get the path of a paticular user.Can you please explain it step by step through coding.I tried a lot.
Thanks

Comment: `FileManagement` is your model right ? update your question with your model definition

Comment: I have to get the Image Path from db through query in HttpGet Method ??

Comment: yeah ! if you're gona display something, httpget gets called, only when you submit something, httppost gets called

Comment: Model.Path have the path of the image but it is in double slash.May be due to this image is not displaying.

Comment: I have updated my code to show you the way i uploaded image.Can you give me the concept how can i have  single slash in path of image??

Comment: Your code is confusing, for simplicity, it must be like 
`Path = "~/App_Data/Uploads" + "/imgname.jpg";`
and storing the entire path in db is not recommended, just have the img name in db and generate url like above.

Comment: It is giving an exception The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path '~/Content/Uploadsd330c5ef-732e-4e6a-aeff-4ab39cb66d0f.IMG_1088 e 6.jpg' is not rooted.

Comment: while saving your image use server.MapPath before your path, while retreving, use without Server.MapPath... sorry to say, but you seriously have to work on your basics..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you only really need one result for getPath, this might clean your code up a bit

```
var imgPath= Session.Query<Registration>()
                 .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Email == UserName)
                 .Select(i => i.Path);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imgPath)
    ViewBag.Imagepath = imgPath;
else
{
    //no user found, handle error
}
```

Other than that your code looks fine, can you debug through your application and see what imgPath is equal to after your query is run?

Answer (score 0):

In case, if the image to be displayed when export to excel from the web page.
Use the server path of the image, otherwise, the image would not be loaded from the assembly image folder.

**Example**:

config:

```
<add key="LogoPath" value="http:\\mysite\\images\\" />
```

code:

```
companyLogo = string.Format("{0}myLogo.png", System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogoPath"]);
```

HTML:

```
<img src='" + @Url.Content(companyLogo) + "' />
```

Comment: Although this construction does work, there are several better and preferable solutions. One of them is in already accepted answer. Your answer require extra work when deploying web to another domain, which is (in production) not a preferable option.

Comment: As I pointed out in my answer, the relative image path will not be found while export the page to excel or another format.